# Centipede-like div following

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Alright, here me out here.**

I am making a bug battle game for web browser using javascript and jquery.

The idea is you click a div as it moves around an arena to do 'damage' to it.

For the final level I want a centipede.

Specifically, I want 4 or 6 divs that **follow each other around** as they move around the arena, similar to the game **snake**.

My question is how can I do this using the avaliable languages? (html, css, javascript, jquery) Is it possible at all? Any help at all will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend using canvas instead of manipulating DOM elements, but obviously that might not work based on how you've made the rest of the game

Comment: The other bugs are just divs with a picture of a bug on them. I want the centipede to be special as it is the final level after all. I will look into using canvas', although I have never really used them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stream of conscious and I'm a bit tired but lets take a stab at it!

I would think your best bet is you're going to have to manage the location of all the squares manually. Annoying but because this is a very non-html layout that is your best bet.

Your HTML would be something like this for the control. Basically a container with 6 divs that will represent the snake's body parts. 0 is the head in my case.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="snakePart0" onclick="moveSnake()"><div>
  <div class="snakePart1"><div>
  <div class="snakePart2"><div>
  <div class="snakePart3"><div>
  <div class="snakePart4"><div>
  <div class="snakePart5"><div>
</div>
```

Now the css would be something like this so that when you set the left and top of each of the snake parts, it gets positioned in place.

```
.container {
  position: relative; // allows top and left on the child elements to work
}
.snakePart0,
.snakePart1,
.snakePart2,
.snakePart3,
.snakePart4,
.snakePart5,{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   position: absolute;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

And finally your javascript would be something like this:

```
var snakePosition = [{0,0},{0,10},{0,20},{0,30},{0,40},{10,40}];
function moveSnake() {
    // removes the last element from the snake since we are moving it
    snakePosition.splice(-1,1);

    // Do some math to make sure your new position of the front of the head doesn't overlap another portion of the snake
    snakePosition.splice(0, 0, {
        top: snakePosition[0].top + math;
        left: snakePosition[0].left + math;
    });        

    // finally rerender the whole snake
    for (var i = 0; i < snakePosition.length; i++) {
       $(".snakePart"+i).top(snakePosition.top);
       $(".snakePart"+i).left(snakePosition.left);
    }
}
```

Obviously you would have to figure out the initialization state here but the render basically should stay the same.

Also your math will likely need to size the container and make sure the snake isn't going outside of it's bounds but that should be a good starting point.

Comment: I purely thought this up in my head right now just because of the words "Alright, here me out here.". Had no idea those words had such an effect on me!

Comment: You can also put a window.settimeout to move the snake automatically. I just used the on click event as it's going to be easier for you to debug.

Comment: Thanks a heap! I'm not exactly the greatest coder nor have much experience but when I had the idea I really wanted it to come to fruition. I'll have a play around with the code and see if I can't make it move erractically like a real centipede!

Comment: Good luck! As I said, it should be a start but there is still a lot of code to be written.

Also, an accepted answer would help me a super amount!